# Emit multiple messages socket.io from one open connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to socket.io, and trying to figure out how to send multiple messages. Here is the scenario I am working on,

```
function setupServer(server) {
    var socketIO = require("socket.io").listen(server);
    socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("client is connected");
        socket.emit('update', { progress: "starting..." })
    });
}
```

I have to call setupServer(server) from another method, and I am receiving "starting..." on client side.

But the problem is, i want to send more/multiple messages LATER ON. Can not send array of messages as my application is building messages strings in say every 10 milliseconds (in a callback function) and i want to send as soon as they are created.

Any solution? Is it possible to get the socket object reference to reuse outside this function?

Comment: In your example there, if you wanted to send a message to all connected users, you could use `socketIO.emit()`. You can store a reference to `socket` inside the `connection` event in an array.

Answer (score 0):

From socket.io docs: http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages

> To broadcast, simply add a broadcast flag to emit and send method calls. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it.

```
function setupServer(server) {
    var socketIO = require("socket.io").listen(server);
    socketIO.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("client is connected");
        socket.emit('update', { progress: "starting..." });

        startBroadCastFromSocket(socket, 3); 

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
          stopBroadcastFromSocket(socket);
        });
    });

    // broadcast message to all sockets
    setInteval(function() {
      broadcastMessageToEveryone(socketIO, {body: 'Hello everyone (FROM SERVER)', timestamp: new Date());
    }, 1000);
}

function broadcastMessageToEveryone(io, body) {
  io.emit('message', {body: body, timestamp: new Date()});
}

function broadcastMessageFromSocket(socket, body) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('message', {body: body, timestamp: new Date()});
}

var socketIntervals = {};

function stopBroadcastFromSocket(socket) {
  if(socketIntervals[socket.id]) {
    clearInterval(socketIntervals[socket.id]);
  }
}

function startBroadcastFromSocket(socket, seconds) {
  socketIntervals[socket.id] = setInterval(function(){
    broadcastMessageFromSocket(socket, 'Hello!');
  }, seconds*1000);
}
```